# How do I get folder sharing working between Ubuntu 20.04 server and my Windows PC's?

Tags: server, 20.04, windows-10, file-sharing

I have a Server in my closet running Ubuntu 20.04 on the boot drive and has a hardware Raid 1 array set up on 2 6TB HDD's.  I want to be able to share the entire 6TB array to all my Windows PC's so I can browse it and keep my library of movies and TV shows on it.

(I had this working already when I had Windows on the server but I'm currently trying to get Steamcache working so I need Ubuntu, but that's a whole other nightmare.)

I have the raid array formatted in NTFS.  I have already right clicked on the drive in Ubuntu and shared it, including checking the guest access box.  However, when trying to access it by mapping it in Windows 10 and entering the login info for the server, I get an error saying I do not have permission.

How can I get this working properly?  Thank you

Comment: Hi Deadboy90. Did you install samba? Did you install a desktop or a server version of ubuntu?

Comment: I did install the "Sharing Service" when prompted by the OS after I set it to share, from what I understand that is Samba.  And I'm running the desktop version of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Just with the install you should be able to see the server. The configuration for Samba is in `/etc/samba/smb.conf`.

Try changing the following line:

```
workgroup = YOURWORKGROUP
```

and add bellow that line:

```
client min protocol = NT1
server min protocol = NT1
```

Also you need to be sure that Windows stations are resolving the server name (meaning converting name to an IP address). You can also try  accessing the IP with `\\\ip\` (as in `\\\192.168.1.x\`) on your explorer's window.

Now, to have a local name resolution you can edit the `C:\windows\system32\driver\etc\hosts` file, on workstations and put `name 192.168.1.x`.

Good luck.

Comment: Pleae. Let me know if it is enough information so you can solve it or you need more detail. I tested it successfully on my home network.

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/391709/911198

In short, it's an oversight in Ubuntu's permission management that you have to manually fix.  The directories for network shares have to be executable for others all the way down to the root, but checking the share with guest box in the UI doesn't ensure that.

Quoting the above answer:

> check permissions on all the directories leading from `/` down to your shared folder too: if ["**other users**"] don't have execute permissions for a directory then they're prevented for accessing any paths below that point, including your share.

> Let's say you wanted to share `/mnt/external/ntfs-drive/folder`. You could add the 'x' permissions on all the parent directories with this command:

> `sudo chmod o+x /mnt /mnt/external /mnt/external/ntfs-drive`

> You also need to set read, write and execute permissions for the shared folder and any contents, but for parent directories execute permission is enough.

For example, it won't work if any of the ancestor directories have permissions like `drwxr-x---` (the default permissions on your home directory at `/home/<username>/`) -- they need to be at least `drwxr-x--x`.  Using the gui to share a directory inside `~` with guest access does not fix this, you have to do it manually.

To see permissions, use `ls -l <path-to-directory>`.  For more information on permissions, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File-system_permissions#Traditional_Unix_permissions

Comment: This is not a propriate answer to users question. You should give an example.

Comment: @ThomasAichinger what is the policy when the answer to another question is the answer to this question?  How do I mark it as a dup?